# Getting error in jenkins build

Tags: android, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-cli

Getting error in Jenkins, while building the project.These are following error "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process."

```
Building on master in workspace D:\Jenkins\jobs\App\workspace
Cleaning local Directory.
java.nio.file.FileSystemException: 
D:\Jenkins\jobs\App\workspace\.\app\app.properties: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.implDelete(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.fs.AbstractFileSystemProvider.delete(Unknown Source)
at java.nio.file.Files.delete(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2180.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at hudson.Util.deleteFile(Util.java:255)
at hudson.Util.deleteRecursive(Util.java:318)
at hudson.Util.deleteContentsRecursive(Util.java:220)
at hudson.Util.deleteRecursive(Util.java:309)
at hudson.Util.deleteContentsRecursive(Util.java:220)
at hudson.scm.subversion.CheckoutUpdater$1.perform(CheckoutUpdater.java:81)
at hudson.scm.subversion.WorkspaceUpdater$UpdateTask.delegateTo(WorkspaceUpdater.java:162)
at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$CheckOutTask.perform(SubversionSCM.java:988)
at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$CheckOutTask.invoke(SubversionSCM.java:969)
at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$CheckOutTask.invoke(SubversionSCM.java:945)
at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:990)
at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:968)
at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.checkout(SubversionSCM.java:894)
at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.checkout(SubversionSCM.java:830)
at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:485)
at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1269)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:607)
at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:529)
at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1738)
at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:410)
Archiving artifacts
Finished: FAILURE
```

What does this mean, and what can I do about it?

Comment: A different process has locked your file.

Comment: Login to your master and examine the running tasks to see if there are any processes locking your file. If you are unable to find it, restart the server and try again

Answer (score 0):

in job configuration page delete workspace option is there. click that option before running the job. Or else if master-slave then check the same file has been used by differ